# Cannot Create Temporary Table using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, native-sql

I cannot able to create temporary table using hibernate here is my code

```
        getSession().beginTransaction();
        String queryString1 = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  sage_temp_table(CRMID VARCHAR(60),POPAmountPaid DECIMAL(14,2)) ";
        getSession().createSQLQuery(queryString1).executeUpdate();
        getSession().flush();
        String queryString2 = "INSERT INTO sage_temp_table(CRMID,POPAmountPaid) SELECT  CRMID,POPAmountPaid FROM sage_payments WHERE sage_payments.`CRMID` REGEXP \"^[0-9]+$\" AND"
                + " sage_payments.POPPaidDate NOT LIKE \"%0000-00-00 00%\" AND sage_payments.POPPaidDate IS NOT NULL AND sage_payments.POPAmountPaid IS NOT NULL";
        getSession().createSQLQuery(queryString2).executeUpdate();
        getSession().beginTransaction().commit();
```

Here in logs it shows commands are running but when i select content from table it says table sage_temp_table does not exist thus is not created and does not give any error.Here are the logs

```
  04:00:04,549 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: CREATE TEMPORARY  TABLE  sage_temp_table(CRMID VARCHAR(60),POPAmountPaid DECIMAL(14,2)) 
  04:00:17,463 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: INSERT INTO sage_temp_table(CRMID,POPAmountPaid) SELECT  CRMID,POPAmountPaid FROM sage_payments WHERE sage_payments.`CRMID` REGEXP "^[0-9]+$" AND        sage_payments.POPPaidDate NOT LIKE "%0000-00-00 00%" AND          sage_payments.POPPaidDate IS NOT NULL AND sage_payments.POPAmountPaid IS NOT NULL
```

Here one more case when i remove TEMPORARY from queryString1 table gets created and insertion also takes place.
Please tell me what is wrong in it?

Comment: Did you solve this already?